# How do I reference multiple columns of a table for autofilter VBA in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, search

I'm working on a signposting directory and I've inserted an active x control Textbox that id like to use as a search box for my "All_Data_Table" Table. I'm editing the VBA to dynamically search and then filter as someone types, across multiple columns and return the results in the same table, but I cannot get it to work.

I've linked the active X textbox to cell A1

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
ListObjects("All_Data_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=("a1")
End Sub
```

I'd like it to search & then filter results that match the text from A1 across columns 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10, and 13

Comment: Do you mean A1 match column 1 AND column 2 AND column 3 etc  in the same row ?

Comment: so A1 is the cell I've linked to the searchbox, so esentially the search criteria will be whatever text is in A1. I would like it to search in columns 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10, and 13 for any matches in cell a1/searchbox

Comment: If you filter (eg) ColA for (eg) "*car*" and that filters out rows which might contain your keyword in other columns, then your approach of filtering all columns can't work (at least using Autofilter it won't, because you can't construct an "OR" filter across multiple columns )  I think you'd need to loop over the table data in code, and hide non-matching rows.